# Does Namecoin support the bootstrap.dat file?

Tags: namecoin, bootstrap.dat

If I create a bootstrap.dat file for Namecoin from an existing install will it use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This feature does not exist (yet) in Namecoin.